# How to include a value from an external bat script

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-file

I have a code that is shared by 6 different bat scripts below that takes an input argument. I wonder if I can externalize this piece in a seperate bat script and import it instead, so everytime I update this piece of code, I don't have to update all 6 bat scripts.

Code:

```
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Prompt
  SET VAR=%1
  GOTO Continue
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Prompt
  set /p VAR="Check which value? "
  GOTO Continue
:Continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using redirection.

Take this solution.bat file

```
    set /p myvar=< somestring.txt
```

Where somestring.txt contains "abc"

myvar will now exist as an environment variable with abc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is supposed to set VAR to the first argument. If the first arg is missing then you want to prompt for a value.

First off, I would simplify your logic.

```
set "VAR=%~1"
if not defined VAR set /p "VAR=Check which value? "
```

Once simplified like above, I don't see why you would feel a need to externalize the code. But it could be done.

In your main script

```
call getArg.bat %1
```

And here is getArg.bat

```
set "VAR=%~1"
if not defined VAR set /p "VAR=Check which value? "
exit /b
```

Comment: @djangofan - Please be more careful with your edits. My original code actually worked, and your edit actually introduced a bug - it was missing percents around VAR. I've reverted back to my original post. It is true that my logic is not quite the same as the OP, but that change is intentional - it is a bit more robust to strip off the quotes during the assignment and do the test with IF NOT DEFINED. The `IF "%VAR%"` test will fail if the argument is already quoted and contains special characters. You might consider posting a comment instead of directly editing. That is how I usually do it.

Comment: i write .bat script every day.  the "if not defined" made sense only if you had not defined VAR, whether its empty or not, but you did.  at first glance it did not appear it would work (although i was wrong) , but regardless, using "var"=="" is more readable in this particular case (IMHO), but as you know, both work.

Comment: It looks like i just have to move the code in my question into another bat script, and simply call it and it will set the ENV in the bat script loading it.